# Creating a sortable tree/grid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, treetable

I'd like to create a tree structure from JSON, but with multiple columns that can be sorted. I've seen lots of implementations of trees and grids but never one mixed.

Does anyone know of a plugin or feature for any Javascript toolkit that can make this happen so I don't have to re-invent the wheel here?

Comment: Hey Eric- Can you please explain this a bit further?  It sounds like you're describing new, but then you're asking for something that exists.. I'm not sure I understand exactly you are trying to build.

Comment: Is it that you have an array of similar in nature JSON object and you want to sort that array of object by one or more key? If so I got what you need :P

Comment: Take a look at http://www.htmltreegrid.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems pretty nice: http://www.max-bazhenov.com/dev/ux.maximgb.treegrid/index.html

Uses ExtJS, which has some licensing limitations you have to consider.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In fact, we are already using Ext-JS. Thank you!!

Comment: For the future, if you're looking for a widget and can describe it, it's probably already been done in ExtJS. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I found all these components:

- [Coqsoft Treegrid](http://www.coqsoft.com/treegrid/www/), commercial, seems the non plus ultra!
- [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/), commercial:

  - [Column Tree](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html) component *
  - [Nested Grid](http://mikhailstadnik.com/ext/examples/nested-grid.htm), that is [Grid Plugin with Row Expander](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html) modified by Mikhail
  - [Ext.ux.maximgb.treegrid](http://www.max-bazhenov.com/dev/ux.maximgb.treegrid/index.php), another mod, by Max (the one proposed by eyelidlessness)
- [JQTreeTable](http://www.hanpau.com/index.php?page=jqtreetable), minimal, requires jQuery *
- [Treetable](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeTable), plugin for jQuery *
- [dojo-treetable](http://code.google.com/p/dojo-treetable/), based on Dojo *
- [Maxdesign](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/tree-table/), it's simply a good css *

* seems not sortable

Personally I'm trying **Treetable** and, after some configurations (rummaging in the examples in the source of the documentation page...), I'm enjoying its simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 3):

After a long research for a treegrid, the best one that I came across is from jeasyui.com

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=TreeGrid

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to have sorting capabiltiies

Answer (score 2):

The [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/documentation) plugin for jQuery tied with its plugin of [jstree-grid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) can handle sorting (sorting is a [plugin to the main jstree](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/sort)) that is quite flexible (and re-uses the jQuery UI theme you apply).

Is that the sort of grid you're looking for? You end up with a view very much like: [image: jstree-grid-with-sort-themerolled]

The sorting by column you'll have to manually add and then [trigger a re-sort](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/5jTBy1Fn2pU).

Comment: Hi, can you please share some codes about the above example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "official" example as well (top grid on the page), using the RowExpander UX.

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid3.html

Comment: @Chau @Jason I think this is the new link: http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/ext-2.0/examples/grid/grid3.html

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX also has the TreeGrid JavaScript component (supports sorting and other grid-related features):
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/

(disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another treegrid with support for bootstrap.
http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/examples/example-bootstrap-3.html